# Change WPF control's ControlTemplate to not be disabled

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, label, controltemplate

I have a Devexpress `DateEdit` and added a trigger for when `IsEnabled=False` to change the `ControlTemplate` to be a `Label`. This all works fine, but my problem is, that the `Text` of the `Label` is still `Grayed out`(Disabled).

My style:

```
<Style x:Key="DateTimeDropDownStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dxe:DateEdit}">
        <Setter Property="Mask" Value="dd MMM yyyy"/>
        <Setter Property="MaskUseAsDisplayFormat" Value="True"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="dxe:DateEdit.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="dxe:DateEdit.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text, StringFormat={}{0:dd MMM yyyyy}}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

So, my question is, how do i change the `Style` so that the `Label` is not disabled?

Comment: 2 ideas come to mind , the first setting the Label iteself to IsEnabled = true at the Label Level ,
the Second use IsReadOnly property instead of IsEnabled.

Comment: @eranotzap I did try setting `IsEnabled=True` but that didn't work. Setting the `IsReadOnly` property is not an option here. I am limited to the `IsEnabled` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `Foreground` on the `Label` in your template.

If it doesn't help, you'd have to edit the control template for the label. A basic one is:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>    
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <!--This is the trigger to remove-->
        <Tirgger Property="IsEnabled"
                 Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Setting the `Foreground` did not help. The text is still "Grayed out"(Label is Disabled). Setting the `ControlTemplate` again did the trick. Thanks =)